# How to implement a auto-update to my app?

Tags: android, deployment

I have an app, and I'll deploy it just from a Website, not from PlayStore.
I would like to implement some way to check if the version that I have installed is the last one.

I was thinking in something like store a hash of the Apk, then when I open the app, check if the hash in internet/server is the same as the one that I have installed.

But Idk how to get a hash of the current apk.

I would like to know if is this a good solution, or if is there a better way to implement an autoupdate.

Answer (score 1):

Dont worry about computing a hash as you can use the value for the Application Version (string) or version code (int) as set in the AndroidManifest.xml on release builds.

To get the version string (or versionCode),

```
String versionName;
int versionCode;
try {
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = manager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    if (packageInfo.versionName != null){
        versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
        versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException ignore){
    versionName = "unreleased"
    versionCode = -1;
}
```

Then use `versionName` or `versionCode` to check if it is equal to what is on your server.